# What is the equivalent of zerofree for vfat (fat 16, fat 32)

Tags: usb, data-recovery, format, fat32, exfat

To make one file unlinked with `rm myfile` on a ext2, ext3 or ext4 formatted USB, I run

```
zerofree /dev/sdb
```

What would be the equivalent command(s) for for FAT16 and FAT32 formatted USB? (i.e USB formatted with `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb`)

Answer (score 1):

For flash memory drives and filesystems that support the TRIM/DISCARD/UNMAP operation(i.e. Telling the disk controller which blocks are no longer used and can be garbage collected), one can use the `fstrim` command to get rid of the unused storage blocks under a certain filesystem:

```
fstrim -v _mountpoint_
```

This is considered to be a disk-friendly alternative to the `zerofree` command as flash memory storage has a limited write cycle count and will be inoperable after depleting it.

Note the execution of the `fstrim` command doesn't necessarily mean that the blocks will be instantly gone, it is the disk controller that determines when to do the garbage collection.  Also not all flash memory storage devices support that operation either.

Answer (score 0):

`zerofree` is overkill for just one file. You want to look at `shred`. It makes no sense to overwrite the entire free space on the disk (possibly one more terabytes) just to overwrite one small file.

`zerofree` will overwrite with zeros all the free space on the disk. If that disk is a SSD or flash drive this will have a negative impact on its lifetime (solid-state devices have a limited number of writes available).

To answer the question as asked: On filesystems where `zerofree` is not available you just use `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=temporary-file bs=1M
rm temporary-file
```